# Smarta tradition comes under which darshan among the Shad Darshanas?

Tags: shad-darshana, smarta

Smarta tradition ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarta_tradition ) comes under "which of the following"  Hindu School Of Philosophy/Darshan: ?

- (1) Samkhya
- (2) Yoga
- (3) Nyaya
- (4) Vaisheshika
- (5) Mimamsa
- (6) Vedanta (If Vedanta, then under which group of Vedanta, ie  Advaita or Vishishtadvaita or Dvaita or Bhedabheda or Dvaitadvaita or Achintya Bheda Abheda or Shuddhadvaita) ?

Comment: This may be exactly what you are looking for: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3796/8635

Comment: Yes, as @Laksh pointed, Smarta are the followers of Adi Shankaracharya, so philosophically comes under Vedanta.

Comment: Advaita Vedanta.

Comment: Advaita philosophy.

Comment: As a general note, not all sects within Hinduism need align to a particular darsana. Darsanas are not "ism"s. Rather they are intellectual exercises in understanding nature and life.