# Is mind-based idol worship superior to the sensory format?

Tags: idols

I always regarded idol worship as requiring the external, physical, gross, but [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6717/16165) it says:

> The Deity form of the Lord is said to appear in eight varieties —
> stone, wood, metal, earth, paint, sand, the **mind** or jewels. [SB -
> 11.27.12]

First, it is not clear to me what mind-based idolatry is.  What exactly is it?  Is is just feeling/emotion? Or more like a visualization technique?
If there an advantage to mind-based idolatry?

[More info regarding Murthi pooja (idol worship).](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/253/16165)

Comment: If you were brought up with images of Gods in childhood - it gets more or less permanently imprinted in the brain and those images would always rise up in the mind if you try to pray in adulthood @blue_ego

Comment: @SK what you say may be so, but what do you mean "try to pry"?

Comment: Yes Manas Puja is better than Bahya Puja .. better in the sense more fruitful