# Who thinks the supreme Shiva's only forms are Nataraja, Dakshinamurthi, and Ardhanarishvara?

Tags: shiva, shaivism, agamas, shaiva-siddhanta

The term "Shaivite" is overused nowadays. For instance, Iyer Brahmins are often called Shaivites, but they're actually followers of Adi Shankaracharya's Smartha sect (which I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3796/36) and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2480/36)), and simply adopt Shiva as their Ishta Devata. True philosophical Shaivism is relatively rare nowadays (in contrast to Vaishnavism which is pretty common). I discussed one genuine Shaivite sect, the Lingayat sect of Basava, in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6621/36). But my question is about a more famous sect of Shaivism, known as Shaiva Siddhanta, which is based on the Shaiva Agamas and the poems of the Nayanars just as the Sri Vaishnava sect (of which I'm a member) is based on the Pancharatra Agamas and the poems of the Alwars.

Now the Shiva Tattva Viveka is a work by the 16th century Shaiva Siddhanta philosopher Appaya Dikshitar which seeks to show that Shiva is supreme.  In [this excerpt](https://preview.ibb.co/jVVei5/image.jpg) from the Shiva Tattva Viveka, Appayya Dikshitar makes a distinction between Paramashiva, whom he considers to be the supreme Brahman, and Rudra, the god of destruction who's part of the Trimurthi.  And then he addresses the question of what forms of Shiva are forms of Paramashiva as opposed to Rudra:

> Now among the images of Shiva described in the Puranas, etc., which are of Paramashiva and which are of Rudra with attributes? **Some say that the form with the blissful dance, i.e., Anandatandaveshvara, the second being Dakshinamurti and the third one being Ardhanarishvara in the dancing posture.  Only those forms are of Paramashiva.  Other forms are of Rudra endowed with guna.**  We do not like it, because in Yogayagnavalkya, Paramashiva is mentioned in the form of the five-faced Sadashiva[.]... In the Kurma Purana... [Shiva's] image as sitting with Uma as his consort and holding the trident weapon is mentioned with the words "athanvapashyadgirisham ... sanatana,". Therefore according to the teachers of the Agamas, other forms of Paramashiva should also be accepted.  They are not shown here because the judgment about them is very secret and can be understood only with the instruction by a guru.

[image][image][image]

For those who don't know, Anandatandeshvara refers to Nataraja, the dancing form of Shiva whom I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6886/36). Dakshinamurthi refers to the South-facing young sage form of Shiva whom I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7896/36). And Ardhanarishvara refers refers to the half-Shiva half-Parvati form.  It seems that "some" people say that these are the only three forms of Paramashiva and that other forms are merely forms of Rudra, but Appaya Dikshitar criticizes this view and says that the five-headed Sadashiva form whom I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9989/36) as well as the form of Shiva holding a Trishula and sitting next to Parvati are also forms of Paramashiva.  He says his view is the view of the teachers of the Shaiva Agamas, which I assume refers to Shaiva Siddhanta Acharyas.

But my question is, who believes that Nataraja, Dakshinamurthi, and Ardhanarishvara are the only three forms of Paramashiva?  I've never heard of this view before.  It's strange that someone would believe that the five-headed Sadashiva form is a manifestation of Rudra.  But I suppose it's possible in principle for a Shaivite sect to deny the existence of five-headed Sadashiva altogether

In any case, does anyone know what Shaivite sect believes this?  And does this sect still exist?

Comment: At the very least Shiva is considered aSTa mUrti (having 8 forms). So this limited view that Appayya Dikshita is countering is likely a view held by a few and held only for a small period of time. Since it had no credence, it did not gain popularity nor did it endure. I don't think it is necessary to pursue its provenance.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Well, the people that Appaya Dikshitar is criticizing didn't disbelieve in other forms of Shiva, it's just that they classified them as forms of Rudra as opposed to forms of Paramashiva.

Comment: before sankara iyers did not exist if so what were they called ?

Comment: Still unnecessary, I feel.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Well, I find it interesting that such people existed, so I'd like to find out more about their belief system if possible.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi The term Iyer existed before Adi Shankaracharya.  Iyer is the Tamil word for Brahmana.  But then Sri Vaishnava Brahmins started calling themselves Iyengars, because of the 5 Angas of Sharanagati.  And so then the Brahmins who still called themselves Iyers as opposed to Iyengars were mainly the followers of Adi Shankaracharya, so the word Iyer eventually became a term for Brahmins who follow Adi Shankaracharya.

Comment: but i know many who are not strict followers of sankara and are like normal brahmins. further many kerala brahmins including namboodiris denounce sankara

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Yeah, some Iyers may not know much about the doctrines of Adi Shankaracharya, just like some Iyengars may not know much about the doctrines of Ramanujacharya.  But if you look at any Iyer Brahmin's ancestry, you'll find that he's descended from followers of Adi Shankaracharya.

Comment: it looks like brahmins were called iyers but it was vaishnavas who wanted some fancy elite status and hence separated as iyengars and started separate customs like thicker sacred thread and different style of wearing saree to look different and special from iyers.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi It's not about elite status, it's about humility.  It's about Sharanagati or complete surrender to Sriman Narayana.

Comment: that humility is not possible by continuing with the name iyer ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Certainly it's possible to be humble while being called an Iyer.  But what I'm saying is that the name Iyengar is related to the concept of Sharanagati, and Sharanagati has to do with humility, not elite status.

Comment: Parama Shiva obviously has 6 forms. Anyways, what purpose does the first para in the Q serve?

Comment: @Rickross Well, what is "obvious" to you might not be true according to others.  Different sects believe in different forms of Brahman.  And the first paragraph is to introduce the Shaiva Siddhanta sect to those who may not be familiar with it.

Comment: Which sects according to you will discuss Parama Shiva to start with?  People who at least have some knowledge on ParamaShiva will all know that he pervades everything in his 6 forms. @KeshavSrinivasan And the first para is completely redundant IMO. And if that really was the motive, Saiva Siddhanta's wiki would have been a far better teacher than ur' passage.Also why Iyers dragged in? Even that is not irrelevant?

Comment: Lots of different Shaivite sects believe in different forms of Shiva.  In any case, the stuff about Iyers is a way to explain to people who don't know as much what kind of sect Shaiva Siddhanta is.

Comment: Quoting from an English translation of Linga Purana, 

"Before starting to create, Brahma told Shiva, “Please help me out by creating some beings, I can not cope on my own.”

Shiva gladly agreed and started to create beings who were just like him in appearance. These came to be known as the Rudras.

“What are you doing?” exclaimed Brahma. “Don’t create immortal beings who are like yourself. Create beings who are mortal.”

“That I flatly refuse to do,” replied Shiva.

“Then please desist from creating,” requested Brahma. “I shall take care of creation myself.”"

Comment: I would thus endorse the Saguna aspect of Shiva in all its forms which start from Parashiva, which can either be considered Nirguna, or Panchanan in Saguna. So all the other forms range from Parashiva according to my learning. And Parashiva is one of the other synonymous terms for Brahman/Atman etc, which can be referred to in the Nirguna aspect.

Comment: That's what I have learned though.

Comment: All the Rudra and Arudra roopas and other incarnations like Hanuman etc, branch from Sadashiva.