# What to do when scriptures go against conscience?

Tags: scripture, dharma

**TL;DR WHAT TO DO WHEN SCRIPTURES GO AGAINST CONSCIENCE?**

What to do when Parshara Smriti go against my conscience? How can I treat a chandala (I do not even know what that means, except that it is a low caste) differently from a Vaishya? How are they different? Even if they did bad karma, does not mean I will not even look at them. And there are verses that say menstruating women are impure. I can understand that. But, one verse was especially immoral, from chapter 7-

> The mother, and the father, and likewise the eldest brother, all these
>   three relatives will go to hell, if before menstruation they neglect
>   to marry the girl

What kind of Dharma has been prescribed in Parashara Smriti? Marrying a girl so young? I have come to believe Parashara smriti is highly interpolated.

In any case, the question stands. If a scripture goes against my conscience, will I attain bad karma if I do not follow it. This is a general question and does not pertain to Parashara Smriti.

Comment: All the smritis say the same .. if u think ur conscience is good enough a guide then for u consulting any of those scriptures is redundant

Comment: All the smriti-s say the same while all evidences from our epics and puranas say the opposite, implying that all these parts of the smrities are interpolations!

Comment: Just an add-on, Chandal is a person who works in a crematorium (Sham-shan-ghat), collecting woods, clean-up, and maintenance of the place.

Comment: smritis, by definition, are written by man. different smritis were made in different times in different locations to suit different circumstances and consequently give different advice. to be Hindu means to follow the 3 prasthanas; the Gita, brahma sutras, the upanishads - not to follow every smriti.

Comment: @Rickross, by that logic, a thief can 'consult' his conscience and happily steal. the reason why we have scriptures is that humans are very good at confusing desires with conscience. why even have rules if we can do whatever we want and then justify it later as conscience ?

Comment: That is precisely my point too ... @ram

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda speak for yourself, not for all hindus! shaivas accept shiv purana, vaishnavas Vishnu purana! also, gita itself is a smriti text! it is part of the Mahabharata!

Comment: " to be Hindu means to follow the 3 prasthanas; the Gita, brahma sutras, the upanishads " --- who told you that? no such rule is written in any Hindu scripture. Those are just some man made rules.@SwamiVishwananda

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sri Krishnaprem, the great Gaudiya Vaishnava saint ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krishna_Prem) writes in His 'Cruelty and Religion'

> **However divine the ShAstras may have been in its origin, it has been transmitted to us through the memories and writings of purely human beings who like all human beings are subject to error...There are many other practices which..are..intolerable cruelties...If we once admit the principle that Bhagavan would never sanction,let alone command cruelty, we must then fearlessly erase from our religions teachings of all such acts however well-established they may be**.(The Search For Truth, page 115-6).

Krishnaprem further writes

> Does the Lord of all sanction the cruelty or not?.. The Upanishads, the Gita, the Bhagawata, the Mahabharata are filled throughout with teachings setting forth in unmistakable terms the duty of love and compassion to all beings and thses lofty teachings, the crest jewel of the Sanatana Dharma, should be allowed to overrule by divine right all lesser or narrower teachings.Do not fear that the whole structure of Hindu religion will be weakened by such criticism. The Sanatana Dharma is no decayed house that will crumble to pieces at a touch. It is built of the rock of Eternal Truth and its sublime beauty will only shine out more replendently than ever if the mud plaster with which selfish men have covered it up be removed...MA hinsyAt sarvabhutAni--"Do injury to no living being!" This is subtle teaching of the Veda.

MahAjano yena gatah sa panthAh--I think He answered your question.

**UPDATE**

Please see how contradictory the sayings of our Smriti-s are regarding the age of marriage of a girl with the evidence avalable in our epics and puranas.The Baudhayana, Gautama, Vasistha or Parashara Smriti-s all recommend marriage before her reaching puberty! And what do we see in our Ramayana, Mahabhara and the Puranas? Was Sita or Parvati or Draupadi or Damayanti or any such female character got married 'while running nacked' as advised by the Smriti-s? No. They were matured enough and chose or being chosen by their husbands themselves. The Swayamvara obviously was never held for a girl who does not understand the meaning of marriage! I think it makes it clear that no such injunction existed originally, which leads to a conclusion that all these slokas of the Smriti-s recommending child marriage are interpolations of some later time when this was somehow needed by the society.

https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.128125

Comment: @ShashwatAsthana I have provided the link.Please read that book.

Comment: Okay, I will do so.

Comment: @ShashwatAsthana And todays we must obey our constitution!

Comment: 'what do we see in our Ramayana, Mahabhara' - Neither Sita's nor Draupadi's marriage was a svayaṃvara. They were won (vīryaśulka).

Comment: @sv. Yes, but NOT at the age when they were ' running naked'!

Comment: You mentioned four female characters and used the term Swayamvara. I'm saying 2 out of 4 were prize money (vīryaśulka). I don't know whether they were 'running naked' or reached puberty at the time of marriage.

Comment: @sv. The maturity of their characters reveal that they were not child.

Comment: you're completely wrong about puranic characters. sita devi was 6, parvati devi also a balya (when himavan took her to meet shiva), draupadi was 16 (she was directly born out of fire at age of 16, to be ready for swayamvara).

Comment: @ram According to the CE Sitadevi was NOT six at the time of marriage.There are so much variations in different puthis of the Ramayana!

Comment: @commonman, what is CE ?

Comment: @ram Critical Edition

Answer (score 12):

The answer to this question is given in scripture itself and in the writings of the greats. Scripture can be regarded as scripture only if it is reasonable.

Bhishma said in Mahabharata

> 'Even the words heard from an ignorant person, if in themselves they
> be fraught with sense, come to be regarded as pious and wise. In days
> of old, Usanas said unto the Daityas this truth, which should remove
> all doubts, **that scriptures are no scriptures if they cannot stand
> the test of reason.**'

*Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CXLII*

Acharya Shankara, for example, in his Gita Bhasya says:

> "The appeal to the infallibility of the Vedic injunction is
> misconceived. The infallibility in question refers only to the unseen
> forces or apurva, and is admissible only in regards to matters not
> confined to the sphere of direct perceptions, etc. ..... **Even a
> hundred statements of sruti to the effect that fire is cold and
> non-luminous won't prove valid. If it does make such a statement, its
> import will have to be interpreted differently. Otherwise, validity
> won't attach to it. Nothing in conflict with the means of valid
> cognition or with its own statements may be imputed to sruti**."

*REF: Srimad Bhagavad Gita Bhasya of Sri Sankaracarya 18.66 translation by Dr. A. G. Krishna Warrier, p629;*

Yoga Vasistha Ramayan says:

> “The remark of a child is to be accepted, if it is in accordance with
> reason; **but the remark of even Brahma Himself, the creator of the
> world is to be rejected like a piece of straw if it does not accord
> with reason.**”

*REF: Vasistha's Yoga II.18 translated by Swami Venkatesananda, p 35;*

Sri Vacaspati Misra, another Advaita Vedanta philosopher, says,

> "Even one thousand scriptural statements cannot transform a jar into a
> piece of cloth".

*REf: quoted by Radhakrishnan in his book, 'Indian Philosophy'.*

Manu Smriti (4.176) advises discarding traditions and customs which offend people.

> However, **discard** the desire (kama) and material wealth (artha) if contrary to Dharma; as also, **any usage or custom or rules regarded as source of Dharma if at any time they were to lead to unhappiness or arouse people's indignation.**

**Rejection of discriminatory verses**

Any discriminatory verse in Hindu scripture is also automatically invalid according to Hindu scripture and should not be followed. This is necessary because Hinduism is not an organized dharma and does not have any central body to oversee the content of Hindu spiritual texts.

> **If a holy act is against the interest of other members of the society,
> it should not be practiced.** It is Dharma which is the source of Artha
> and even of Kama.

**Kurma Purana I.2.54**

Swami Vivekananda has advised rejection of those parts of Smritis and Puranas that are offensive.

> **The Smritis and the Puranas are productions of men of limited
> intelligence and are full of fallacies, errors, the feelings of class
> and malice.** **Only parts of them breathing broadness of spirit and love
> are acceptable, the rest are to be rejected.** The Upanishads and the
> Gita are the true scriptures.

*The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda/Volume 6/Epistles - Second Series/CXXIV*

Comment: _but the remark of even Brahma Himself, the creator of the world is to be rejected like a piece of straw if it does not accord with reason_ - does this mean when something Vivekananda says is unreasonable, it needs to be rejected as well?

Comment: Of course. Ultimately it is the reader of the scripture or any text who decides what is reasonable. Sri Krishna says in Gita 18.63, '..Reflecting on this entire teaching, do as you think fit'. There is no need to be slave of either scripture or of any one. This Hindu position is utterly different from the position of the Abrahamic faiths which stress blind belief.

Comment: And who is going to judge what Bhishma said is reasonable or not? I mean there has to be a hierarchy of judges .. to me its completely unreasonable because scriptures talk about those truths which we can not discover by sensory methods (reasoning) .. and what about Swami Vivekanada? Is he authorized somewhere in the Vedas to call the Vedic Rishis men of limited intelligence? What is the guaranty that he is talking sense? @PradipGangopadhyay Who is going to judge all that?

Comment: @Rickross, you have already judged Vivekananda or Bhishma's statements as unreasonable. Good for you. You have already answered your question. I find both Bhishma and Vivekananda to be reasonable. Where is the need for any hierarchy? Every spiritual aspirant will have to make their own judgement.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay Neither did I answer the Q nor did u .. what u did is talking of subjectivity but in religion it does not work like that because Laws are fixed .. Vivekananda calling Vedic Rishis fools is completely unacceptable to me because our religion is indebted to those Rishis .. If they had not composed the scriptures  what will Vivekananda  comment upon? What will he deal with? Our religion is called Arsha Dharma - the religion of the Rishis  and he is calling them fools ..fine but who will judge his intelligence? Yes, there has to be a hierarchy of judges

Comment: What do you make of [BG 16.23](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=ro&field_chapter_value=16&field_nsutra_value=23&etgb=1) quoted in the other answer? Can one be "happy" by not following "scriptural injunctions"? The same person could not have written so many contradicting verses in the BG.

Comment: @sv BG 16.23 and 18.63 are not contradictory. BG 16.23 is saying that BG will be of value to a spiritual aspirant and should not be summarily rejected by the reader. BG 18.63 is asking the aspirant to reflect on its teachings and behave accordingly. If all one has to do is to blindly accept scriptural teachings then what is the need for reflection? Just go through the discussion here. Bhishma's teaching about the need for reasonableness is in scripture. Bhishma's teaching is being rejected by some people here while saying that scriptural injunction must be obeyed.

Comment: Can one be happy by not following scriptural injunction? Well the krishna murthi in Dakshineswar Kali temple was damaged around 1860. Rani Rashmoni the temple owner was told about the scriptural injunction to throw the damaged murthi into Ganga and install a new murthi. She asked Ramakrishna about the injunction. Ramakrishna asked her whether she will throw her son in law into the river if he broke his leg. Ramakrishna instead asked her to repair the damaged Murthi and in fact himself repaired it. The repaired Krishna Murthi is still worshipped in the D Kali temple.

Comment: Great answer. This should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: Can you please undelete [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38004) answer?You had undeleted it once before but some users have deleted it again...

Comment: Thanks for undeleting. Another answer of mine also got deleted: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/40561. Can you undelete this as well?

Comment: @SayNoToCensorship The Bhagavad Gita has the least contradictory verses and that's because Arjuna himself at first thinks it is. When Krishna says one Yoga is better than another, however, he sums it up in the last few chapters. I used to have trouble understanding it, but now I don't. Krishna states yes one who follows scriptural teaching will eventually attain moksha this is a valid fact, but Arjuna can still ponder for himself and decide if he finds Krishna to be some maya or if what he is saying has truth or scriptural injunction in it.

Answer (score 5):

"What to do when scriptures go against conscience?"

When scriptures go against conscience, one must change their conscience to match scriptures.

One's conscience is not a guide regarding dharma because it is not a pramana. Many people have different conscience, and the asuric / rakshasa people have their own conscience that is against dharma.

So conscience cannot be a guide.

Confirmed by Krishna in Bhagavad Geeta:

> 16.23: "He who discards scriptural injunctions and acts according to his own whims attains neither perfection, nor happiness, nor the supreme destination"

Comment: Answers on this site should be backed up with proper sources. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer I hv provided quote now

Comment: Partly true and partly false. One must indeed reason with scripture first analyzing it free from bias. Being a skeptic is good it's how I got my connection with the Bhagavad Gita.

Comment: However, some scriptures that aren't Sanatana or show proof of corruption to Vaishnavas the Shiv Purana, etc may be discarded.

Answer (score 2):

> What kind of Dharma has been prescribed in Parashara Smriti? Marrying
>   a girl so young? I have come to believe Parashara smriti is highly
>   interpolated.

Then you have to believe that all other similar scriptures were also interpolated. Because every such scriptures contain such injunctions.

Smritis elaborate the Vedic way of life. And, the Dharmasutras are part of the [Kalpas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalpa_(Vedanga)), which (Kalpa) is one of the six Vedic limbs.

From the Introduction of the [book Dharmasutras - Patrick Oilvelle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0192838822):

> **The Dharmasutras are part of the Vedic Supplements** and are written
>   primarily in the sutra style, even though verses are interspersed and
>   the sutras are not as succinct as those of Panini. The Dharmasutras
>   form part of the ‘ritual expositions’ known collectively as
>   Kalpasutras that include three types of expositions: S´rautasutras
>   dealing with vedic rituals, Grhyasu¯tras dealing with domestic
>   rituals, and Dharmasu¯tras.

So, let's see what these Dharmasutras have to say about the subject.

**Baudhayana DharmaSutras:**

> A man should give his daughter in marriage while she still runs naked
>   to a man of good qualities who has maintained his vow of chastity, or
>   even to a man lacking good qualities; let him not hold back a girl who
>   has started to menstruate.
>
> **If a man does not give his daughter in marriage within three years
>   after she has reached puberty, he undoubtedly incurs a guilt equal to
>   that of performing an abortion**
>   **(4.1.8.11-12)**

**Gautama Dharmasutras:**

> When three menstrual periods have passed, a girl may discard the
>   jewellery her father has given her and join herself on her own to a
>   man of blameless reputation. 21**A girl shall be given in marriage
>   before she reaches puberty, and a man who fails to give her incurs a
>   sin**. 23According to some, she should be given in marriage before she
>   begins to wear clothes.
>
> **(18.20-23)**

**Vashishta DharmaSutras**

> If due to her father’s negligence a girl here is given in marriage
>   after her proper time has elapsed, she, who was made to wait, brings
>   ruin to her giver, like a teacher’s fee that is paid after the time
>   has passed.
>
> **Out of fear that she should menstruate, a father should give a girl
>   in marriage while she still goes about naked, for if she remains in
>   his house after puberty her father becomes guilty of a sin**. 71 As many
>   menstrual periods a girl has while men of equal class are asking for
>   her hand in marriage and she herself is willing, so many foetuses do
>   her parents kill––so states the Law.
>
> **(17.57.70-72)**

Similar verses are there in all other similar scriptures including Apasthambha Dharamsutras etc.So, when what all the scriptures say is going against what we feel as "correct" then we can discard our thinking.

Because the sages who gave these laws are said to be omniscient.

> Manu Smriti 2.7. Whatever law has been ordained for any (person) by
>   Manu, that has been fully declared in the Veda: for that (sage was)
>   omniscient.

But of course we can't follow this sort of instructions now but for that we can not blame the scriptures.

Allied reading from [Kanchi Paramacharya's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrashekarendra_Saraswati) book [Hindu Dharma](http://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part18/chap5.htm):

> **Eight Forms of Marriage**
>
> The eighth and last is paisaca. In asura even though the girl's
>   willingness to marry the man is of no consequence, at least her people
>   are given money. In raksasa, though violence is done to the girl's
>   family, the marriage itself is not against her wish. Rukmini loved
>   Krsna, did she not? In paisaca the girl's wish does not count, nor is
>   any money or material given to her parents. She is seized against her
>   wish and her family antagonised.
>
> We have the brahma type at one end and the paisaca at the other. There
>   cannot be the same system or the same arrangement for everybody. Our
>   sastras have taken into account the differences in temperament and
>   attitude among various sections of people and it is in keeping with
>   the same that they have assigned them different rites, vocations, etc.
>   All our present trouble arises from the failure on the part of men,
>   who advocate the same system for all, to recognise this fact.
>
> There are tribals living in the forests who look fierce and have a
>   harsh way of life. But at heart they may be more cultured than
>   townspeople, not to speak of the fact that they are useful to society
>   in many ways. They have frequent family feuds. In consideration of
>   this raksasa and paisava marriages may have to be permitted in their
>   case. After the marriage, they are likely to forget their quarrels and
>   live in peace with each other. Ksatriyas who are physically strong and
>   are used to material pleasure are allowed the gandharva form of
>   marriage and their girls have even the right to choose their husbands
>   as in the svayamvara ceremony.
>
> It is for these reasons that the dharmasastras, which are based on the
>   Vedas and which constitute Hindu law, permit eight forms of marriage.
>   In all these eight, the bride and groom have the right to be united in
>   wedlock with the chanting of mantras. But brahma is the highest of the
>   eight forms. **In it the bride must not have attained puberty. "Pradanam
>   prak rtoh": -- this statement is in the dharmasastras themselves. A
>   girl's marriage, which has same significance for her that the
>   upanayana has for a boy, must be performed when she is seven years old
>   (or eight years from conception)**
>
> Unfortunately, in the case of some girls, a groom does not turn up in
>   time for a brahma marriage to be performed. Meanwhile, they grow old
>   and their marriage is conducted in the arsa, daiva, or prajapatya way.
>   Only these types are permitted for Brahmins. But for the rest other
>   types are also allowed. They may marry a girl who has come of age
>   either in the gandharva way or in a svayamvara.

Related article you can read: [Controversy about Age of Marriage](http://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part18/chap4.htm).

Comment: I think we should feel ashamed while quoting from this smritis.A girl while running naked will have to marry a man who have maintained his vow or even to to a man lacking good qualities--so that husband can take wife on his lap I suppose? Which of our Devis--Radhika,  or Parvati etc were married at this age? Which deity couples are shown in our ancient temples with such huge age difference? If one Smriti can have interpolation, why not others? Why would God or saints want to ruin the innocent girls' lives? I am really very very surprised!!

Comment: What was the age of Draupadi?Of Sakuntala? Which of the female characters in our epics or Kavyas were married while running naked? Their parents were not aware of the Dharmashastras I suppose? Janaka, Drupada, Kanva--all went to hell!! These are clear instances of shameful interpolations probably done to save the girls from the evil eyes of the foreign invaders.

Comment: I cant quote the kind of ref u have quoted in ur answer so i m always going to quote these scriptures if there is opportunity @commonman

Comment: Sorry i do not have much idea about ramayana, mahabharat , draupadi etc ... if u know their details then u can add those to ur answer @commonman

Comment: Yes, you prefer authors like Patrick Ollivelle as you have quoted in other answer :D

Comment: No I prefer scriptures only ..Here too I am quoting from scriptures and not from novels written by Patrick Olivelle @commonman

Comment: To me, sayings of saints are more important as they have eyes to see.

Comment: @commonman, "Which of our Devis--Radhika, or Parvati etc were married at this age" - all of them. Krishna's bala-leela were complete before he was 10. Parvati was taken by her father Himavan to see Shiva when she was was a Balya. Draupadi was 16 during her swayamvara. If a girl is not married by the time she reaches puberty, she is supposed to wait 3 more years, then take a man by herself. so 13 + 3 - 16 was the age of swayamvar for most girls. Janaka 'fell into sea of sadness' when Sita devi was already 6 years old, since a groom hadn't appeared yet. Sri Rama was 12 during their Swayamvar.

Comment: @commonman, your 21st century mindset is probably corrupting marriage and sex, that's maybe why you feel ashamed, and call it 'ruining innocent girls life'.. do you know how many innocent girls' lives are ruined because they are NOT married early ?

Comment: @ram so according to you a girl runned naked upto 13 years?

Comment: @ram marriage and purity are related, so age must be a consideration,This does not mean girls would get narried at 5/6 years of age!

Comment: @commonman, that 13+3 number is only for those girls whose parents do not marry the girls off. it's the parents duty to marry them before puberty. if the parents don't then she is supposed to wait for 3 years after puberty.

Comment: @commonman, yes, they would get married around 6. you are simply not aware of it. i know personally orthodox brahmins who got married at 18, at 13, and heard of 10. and this was not even 100 years ago. many parents who wait until the girls are 20, owing to 'societal pressure', end up lamenting when their girl runs off with some low-caste guy or muslim.

Comment: @ram yes, I know of this. But sorry can not support.It was introduced because of some social reasons.

Comment: @commonman, who are you to support or decry it? it was not 'introduced' because of social reasons. it was 'removed' because of social reasons. Like i mentioned in my answer, the scriptures show the way to get 100% marks. but people can't do that, so they make a rule that 35% is good enough for pass mark. that's why age of marriage increase by sharda act to 16. because many men were too degraded to have innocent attachment to younger girls. because society degraded, concession was made. don't bring down shastras to satisfy the current crop of men.

Comment: @ram I have quoted from Krishna prem. Another from Swamiji.They both agreed that our smriti-s contain interpolations and I find that right.In that sense I support.

Comment: @commonman, vivekananda was un-orthodox in his beliefs and actions. again, that is only so that the tamasic people get awoken. he has specifically mentioned that first, go steal instead of sleeping, then do charity. tamas-rajas-satva is the order. his guru ramakrishna's bride sarada devi was 5 during marriage. if it was against shastras you think ramakrishna himself would have done it ??

Comment: Sri Ramakrishna was not a common man and I exclude Him. His marriage was not a marriage in the sense it is understood.The saints normally obey lokachara and deshachara. But Swamiji did not support this and as I wrote, there is no evidence of child jarriage known to me in our ancient books.

Comment: @commonman, i have already mentioned there is plenty of evidence, you are simply ignorant of those. don't try to brush aside ramakrishna's marriage. saints  never do adharma. you are saying it is adharma. saints may do things out of ordinary, but not adharma. suppose ramakrishna supported it and vivekananda rejected it, whose advice will you take ? vivekananda's goal was to awaken the lower-strata of people. for them child marriage is not recommended. once you reach higher step in ladder, you have to fine-tune the rules.

Comment: @ram is it? Then pl. rectify the answers in https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22230/what-was-the-age-of-sita-at-the-time-of-marriage

Comment: @commonman, did you read that link? it clearly says Sita devi was 6.

Comment: @ram It says She was 16

Comment: @commonman, only one answer says that. that too based on his own logic that dasha means dasharatha and not 10. the other answer shows it was 6.

Comment: @ram No answer says six!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93266/discussion-between-ram-and-commonman).

Comment: Use chat-room for extended further discussion.

Comment: Chandogya Upanishad also talks about someone having a minor wife .. so it must be the common practice in ancient times: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29181 @ram

Comment: Can somebody explain me what is means about a girl running naked? I'm not being able to comprehend.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury I'm thinking that means a very little girl. That's why this answer hurts so much to me. The very reason for me asking the question.

Comment: Of course, Krishna is actually referring to the Vedas, not to the Smritis. It's anachronistic to think that he's referring to the Smritis, since they didn't exist in their present form at the time that Krishna spoke, nor at the time when Vyasa wrote the Gita down.

Comment: Manu Smriti is much more ancient than Mahabharat .. what are you even talking about? @TerjijKassal

Comment: @Rickross Not in it's present form.

Comment: You remind me of the sceptic user Varun Rao @TerjijKassal

Comment: @Rickross Well, your feelings are wrong, because I am not a skeptic.

Answer (score 0):

> Just because they did bad karma, does not mean I will not even look at them

Yet you, and most of society, already follows this. There are criminals locked up in jail that have committed such horrid crimes you would not even want to look at them, let alone shake hands or eat with them. Maybe you are not aware of the type of crimes a person has committed that results in his birth as a chandala.

Btw, there are 2 types of chandala - jati and karma (birth and action)

Jati chandala - Due to bad action in *previous* birth, born as chandala in current birth

Karma chandala - Due to bad action in *current* birth, considered as chandala in current birth.

By that definition, a brahmana drinking liquor may fall under this category. Shastras say the Karma chandala is to be treated worse than Jati chandala.

> [Na karyamaavasatyena naagnihotrena vaa punah, sa bhavetkarma chandaalo
>   yastu dharma paraangmukhah](https://archive.org/stream/EssenceOfParaasharaSmriti/Essence%20of%20Paraashara%20Smriti_djvu.txt)
>
> That house holder who has no respect for Dharma, especially if a
>   Brahmana, is as fallen like the worst human being.

---

> one verse was especially immoral, and luckily goes against the law of my country.. Marrying a girl so young?

You're confusing 2 things - marriage and sex. Sex is based on carnal desire. Marriage need not be based on carnal desire, although it commonly is.

The reason for child marriage, Sharda act is discussed in [another question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17704/what-was-the-true-reason-behind-the-practice-of-child-marriage/18602#18602). Repeating some points here

In olden days, when child-marriage was prevalent, most people had their Kama under control. Both the boy & the girl would be quite young. Hence Kama would not have even entered their hearts. In that age of innocence, if a platonic attachment is formed, it lasts much longer and stronger than an infatuation based just on looks which comes in older people. And most importantly, there would be no sex until the girl reached menarche. In fact, the girl mostly would stay with her parents until she reach puberty, only then go to her husband & in-laws home.

> I have come to believe Parashara smriti is highly interpolated.

Your belief is wrong.

There is nothing wrong with the Smritis, nor are they interpolated. They are a medicine for the ills in society. But people don't realize that medicine first tastes bitter, and later cures you. They mistake it for poison, which also first tastes bitter, and then kills you.

Carnal desire enters heart during teenage. If at that time, it's not controlled and channeled properly, you can guess what will happen. Society does not allow adolescents to marry before 18, and in most cases, parents don't even bring up topic of marriage until 21 for girls, and 25 for boys. Then what will they do from the age of 14 to 24 for 10 years when the natural urge for sex continuously stirs their mind ? Pornography, and if unchecked, illicit sex, like it happens in the West.

Are you, OP, aware of any normal college going student who has never watched aabhaas adult pictures/videos ?

On the one end, young girls are getting raped, men cheat them saying love, then use & throw them, unwanted pregnancies & heinous abortion crime. On other end, women not getting married because they want to be independent, then when they reach 30 years age, they and their parents lamenting that nobody wants to marry them.

[The solution for both of these is early marriage](http://kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part18/chap5.htm). Not child marriage, since it's against current laws, but there is no valid reason to postpone marriage beyond legal age of 18.

---

> If a scripture goes against my conscience, will I attain bad karma if I do not follow it.

Suppose a thief says "if a law goes against my conscience, will I attain bad karma if I steal?"

First, you and I do not decide shastras or laws. They were also not written by normal human beings' as an another answer claims. That answer links to one Vaishnavite Krishna Prem, who is known for shunning orthodoxy & blind traditionalism.

I know another Vaishnavite [Krishna Premi Anna](https://www.vittalrukmini.org/gurusmaranam-srianna.php), who is known for advocating and following ancient traditions even today.

In Kali Yuga, people are degraded. Hence it is not possible for us to live up to the lofty ideals of Smritis. That is a disability on our part, it's not the fault of Shastras.

In the words of Swami Vivekananda (whom both @commonman and I are ardent fans of):

> **We must always elevate the life to the ideal, not bring down the ideal
>   to the level of our lives now**.

The IDEAL is controlling Kama. The IDEAL is marriage at young age.
We people, being degraded, are unable to live up to it. So we brought some laws in 'constitution' to prevent exploitation of young girls, forced marriage etc. That is completely fine, and required in this age.

It's a little bit like "Law says no bribery allowed. We can't live up to it. So let's bring a new law that says it's OK to bribe through corporate election campaign funds"

Let's not pretend that the Smritis themselves are wrong. They are correct. We can't live up to them, so we gave ourselves some concessions.

> [but we shall not bring down the ideal, just because we are not strong enough for it](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.40632/2015.40632.Vedanta-Kesari-1930-31-Vol17_djvu.txt)

Comment: I have a question for you. Some dharma shastras prescribe horrible punishments for sudras for reciting or hearing vedas. Would you justify them as ok, or would you interpret them as arthavAda or would you reject them or would you explain it in some other way?

Comment: @LazyLubber, like i said before, the ideal is always correct. the specific punishment you're referring to was probably arthavada to highlight gravity of issue, but it's not our place to discuss it, because 1. we dont have adhikara, 2. not aware of any such punishment actually meted out in history. But the end-goal is same - shudras must be prevented from hearing/reciting it. the corollary is equally bad for the brahmanas i.e. brahmanas who DO NOT hear/recite it are to be shunned as much as shudras who hear/recite it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With this attitude, we should not be really surprised if sUdras and avarNas leave Hinduism. India would be in trouble if all these groups leave. Many Hindus in India understand this. However, those who migrate to other countries dont care so much. Hence they adopt a more orthodox attitude compared to their counterparts in India. Just an observation. Could be right or wrong.

Comment: @LazyLubber, that is not a new philosophical problem that our saints were unaware of. It's called 'don't let perfect be the enemy of good'. the reason shudras and avarnas have hatred is because of partial application of rules / double standards. Kanchi Periyavar clearly states the main reason for brahmin-hatred and reason for society degradation is non-performance of vedic studies and rituals and conduct by brahmins. if the leaders themselves don't have self-control, what to expect of followers. they left agrahara to cities, then to foreign countries, now some eat meat/drink/porn etc.

Comment: @LazyLubber,  "India would be in trouble if all these groups leave" - circular logic at its best. the reason India is in trouble is because people don't stick to orthodox practices. it's like saying 'the reason thieves leave is because police are strict'. if a society is made up of people who mostly want to be adharmic, such a society will cease to exist soon enough on its own. if a society is to be protected, it is by protecting the traditions of dharma. protecting a society by giving up its ideals is like protecting the branches by burning the roots.

Comment: very nice poetry @ram but how can you prove that smritis are not interpolated? It is a scholarly consensus that in all smritis (dharmashastras) thee have been interpolations and even the best of the preserved dharmashastras have not been written down by the sages they have been assigned to for example - yanjavalkya smriti, manav dharmashastra/manu smriti.