# Is it permissible to transgress scriptural injunctions when they are against your conscience?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, sin

According to accepted answer for question: [What to do when scriptures go against conscience?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34832/what-to-do-when-scriptures-go-against-conscience) and the second highest voted answer, it is permissible to transgress scripture when scripture is against reason and when you personally feel it is wrong!

My conscience tells me killing and raping is A-Okay! Also, Adolf Hitler has justified in his masterpiece, *Mein Kampf*, that genocide of the weak races is *logical*, and that religious injunctions are irrational!

However, I'm afraid I might go to hell because Krishna says in the Bhagavad Gita:

16.23: "He who discards scriptural injunctions and acts according to his own whims attains neither perfection, nor happiness, nor the supreme destination"!!!

So I am unsure, should I follow Krishna's words or follow my own whims (conscience) like Hitler and kill and rape people!?

Comment: Is it reasonable to kill and rape people? Krishna also says in the Gita 18.63, '...Reflecting on this entire teaching do as you think fit.' So the reader is expected to reflect on the scriptural teaching and then decide to accept it or reject it. So Gita also supports the 'reasonable' position.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay Ur saying Krishna in the geeta supports people to rape and murder?

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay geeta verse 18.63 is not saying 'do what you think is fit', it is saying 'pick from bhakti yoga, karma yoga, gyana yoga as you see fit.' this is in accordance with the commentaries of the great acharyas

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay even if Krishna in the geeta says 'do as you see fit,' it does not negate the fact that sinful acctions lead to narak!

Comment: @Hiranyagarbha, 'reformists' usually preach the 'swaya-buddhi' doctrine, and the average people who don't actually have swaya-buddhi get attracted to it.

Comment: @ram one can be safe to assume that any supposedly 'reform' movement in kali-yuga will actually lead to adharm!

Comment: "My conscience tells me killing and raping is A-Okay!" If your conscience is telling you that killing and raping is ok, then it is time for you to visit a psychiatrist, because your conscience is a statiatical outlier, atleast in the 21st century . On the other hand, my conscience tells me not to harm innocents, and this is same as what most people's conscience would say. So when scripture encourages me to give out harsh punishment to innocent shudras, just for reading vedas, I would ignore scripture and follow my conscience. Hope this helps.

Comment: @LazyLubber "then it is time for you to visit a psychiatrist, because your conscience is a statiatical outlier" Desire to kill and rape is not a mental illness, it is a quality of tamasic buddhi. While it is not common among most humans today, it is a prominent trait among asuric yonis, such as rakhas, asuras, pisachas, etc. Among them, not a statistical outlier!

Comment: @LazyLubber Regarding "innocence," when sudra disregards scriptural viddhi and follows adharma, he is not "innocent", but liable to be punished by the maharaj! Just this way, it is same as Brahmin drinking liquor, he is to be punished by pouring hot liquor into his mouth until he dies!