# Were there religious wars in Hinduism itself? As it was the case for Christian between Catholics and Protestants?

Tags: history, sects, war

An introduction would be better I guess to understand my initiative. I am new here. I am French, and most of the French people do not understand English. So, I want to bring some knowledge to French people who want to know better Hinduism and Satana Dharma to be more global. We have a huge lack of informations in French contents. That's why I ask the stack community, because most of the time your answers are sourced on scriptures contrary to what do people in my FB group... Or what I read in French websites. They only refers to their own mystical experience not to what rishis said. So what I am searching for here is serious people, like many I read here, who answers with sources.

So I asked once, in French contents if there were historical events in hinduism itself, that can blunty be qualified as religious war? All I received is the speech about the tolerance in hinduism but nothing that show if it was the case or not.They just recognized they ignore it actually. So, what I expect is really an historical point, and sourced one, not a philosophic speech. That's not to make a bad painting at all. That's just to know what really happened in the history of this religion. And to take it as a lesson for all of us.

Besides, if it was not a war between hindus theirselves, was there the case with other religions? And if not, how was the harmony ruled? And based on what?

Comment: Since you ask - "if it was not a war between hindus theirselves, was there the case with other religions?", please refer to the following link - https://m.rediff.com/amp/news/column/why-did-sri-lanka-ignore-indias-terror-alerts/20190507.htm  **Emperor Rajendra Chola created a vast empire in South East Asia and invaded Sri Lanka 17 times. During these invasions he destroyed the Buddhist shrines of Anuradhapura and built a Shiva temple at the site.**

Comment: You can also check this Saivaite legend about impalement of Jains in Madurai. (No one knows if it is a legend or based on true events, however, see below).  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impalement_of_the_Jains_in_Madurai  **The massacre of the Jain monks came to be celebrated in some Shaivite temples,[1] including the annual festival at the Meenakshi temple.[6] The impalement of Jains is depicted on the wall frescoes of the Golden Lily Tank of the Meenakshi temple.[7][8] The stone carvings at the Thiruvedagam Shaivite temple also depict the events from the legend.[9]**

Comment: @Tharpa No it is totally true. In France we clearly speak about religions war between protestants and catholics. If you doubt consult the Night of Saint Bartelemy it was a massacre... One of our king was menaced and forced to convert. To not call it religions war is a euphemism.

Comment: @AvyWam  A massacre is not by itself a war.  Forcing an individual to convert is not by itself a war.  Wars have names, e.g. American Revolution, World War I, etc. To say that it was a war is incorrect, an exaggeration.  So my statement was simply correct, and not a euphemism.

Comment: @Tharpa You still does not believe me, here a reference: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronologie_des_guerres_de_Religion_en_France, "guerre" means war. So that's not me who intitulate like this, these are the historians. That's a civil war in France, based on religion. So they called it religions wars.

Comment: @AvyWam Analytical thinking is better than belief. This comment of yours supported your point - your earlier one did not.

Comment: @Tharpa Common... I am not such pretentious to claim historians have not any analytical thinking to qualify it as a war. You can have your point of view, but I gave reference, you still insist, talk in the wind now.

Comment: Can you link the information to/about the war you're talking about? Btw, for seeking historical information, History.SE would also work.

Comment: @Pandya [here](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guerres_de_Religion_(France)) you have the Wikipedia page about the religion wars btw Catholics and Protestant. Do not hesitate to use a translator. I quote the beginning: "we call religion wars a series of conflicts (civil wars, religion wars and military operations) that ravaged the France Kingdom during the second half of XVI century and where were opposed Catholics and Protestants." That's an example. [More](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_wars_of_religion).

Comment: There were, of course, the Muslim invasions (Eng: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muslim_conquests_in_the_Indian_subcontinent , Fre [⭐« bon article »]: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conqu%C3%AAtes_musulmanes_des_Indes )

Comment: As for what has helped keep the harmony? Hindus basically see everyone and everything as One. War requires thinking of the enemy as "otherly" and dehumanization. Nonviolence is also very important in dharmic religions. Despite these core ideas, there is still war and violence in Indian history. Bhagavad Gītā deals with such tension

Comment: Lastly, and sorry I didn't notice this before. Welcome to Hinduism.SE!✨ It's a shame no one welcomed you sooner. Do's and Don't's ( https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/45/10329 ) may still be of some use to you. And, feel free to get deeper into topics with us in chat ( https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=hinduism.stackexchange.com )

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī do not feel sorry, this was not rude anyway. Thank you for your welcome and links.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't go so far as to say that there were religious wars between Hindu sects. There was, however, friction between Saivas (followers of Lord Siva) and Vaishnavas (followers of Lord Vishnu) probably between 5th and 18th century. This friction can be seen in some malicious and embarassing verses in Hindu Puranic literature. I give below one example.

> I abhor the non Vaishnava people and love the Vaishnava ones. I cut
>   off the tongue of the people who reproach Lord Vishnu. With heated
>   liquefied tin I fill the ears of those who hear his reproaches.

*Garuda Purana, Brahma Khanda, Chapter VI.*

Fortunately this type of verses can be easily rejected since Hindu scripture itself says that scripture is no scripture if it does not satistfy the test of reason.

Comment: I did not know there was a "test of reason" That's a point I must learn. I thought that shruti scriptures were superior to smriti ones, simply. Because shruti are blunty divine revelation. But I learnt Puranas were in a very less perfect sanskrit as it is in Vedas, and were adressed to shudras and women. Does it count as shruti anyway?

Comment: What is so-called 'test of reason' you are reffering, and how does it fail the test of reason!? Will you elaborate?!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: "Were there religious wars in Hinduism itself?"

Comment: I found, randomly, this: "Bhisma said in Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CXLII:
    Even the words heard from an ignorant person, if in themselves they be fraught with sense, [..] this truth, which should remove all doubts, that scriptures are no scriptures if they cannot stand the test of reason." on [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2816/does-science-contradict-hinduism/2818#2818). And in Quora, Shashi Mohan Reddy Ravula, gives an answer on [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Hinduisms-view-of-what-to-do-when-science-contradicts-a-statement-in-one-of-its-religious-books).

Comment: @AvyWam go through my answer posted here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34832/what-to-do-when-scriptures-go-against-conscience/34849#34849

Comment: @user18248 test of reason means to check the reasonableness of any text. Is it reasonable to fill the ears with liquified tin merely because these persons have heard about reproaches about Lord Vishnu or cut off the tongues of people who reproach Lord Vishnu? I propose that it is not reasonable and hence the scriptural text cited fails the test of reason and should be robustly rejected.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay How is this unreasonable? It does not violate the Law of Non-Contradiction.