# Are non-Tamil Dravidian languages like Kannada, Telugu, etc. revealed by rishis?

Tags: language, tamil

Folklore in Tamil Nadu says that Tamil was revealed by Shiva to Skanda and then to Agastya, who revealed it to humanity.

Is the same folklore there for the other Dravidian languages like Kannada, etc.?

Comment: Related [What Mleccha languages are used in the Vedas according to Purva Mimamsa?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15121/3500)

Comment: As per some historians, telugu has origins in Magadha Prakrit.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Magadha prakriti is from Sanskrit, and Sanskrit and Telugu aren't even in the same language family, so I doubt that

Comment: That is modern day classification by British Indologists. Telugu poets from many centuries consider "Sanskrit is mother of all Indian languages". "జనని సంస్కృతంబు సకల భాషలకును దేశ భాషలందు తెలుగు లెస్స/‘Janani Samskrutambu sakala bhaashalakunu DeaSa bhaashalandu Telugu lessa;" says Vinukonda Vallabharaya. View of Telugu poets since yore is very different from Indologists

Comment: @TheDestroyer Dravidian languages don't even match with Sanskrit on basic things like numbers (1-10), etc. pronouns, family words (father, mother, etc).  Compare this to Latin "Pater" and Sanskrit "Pita" and you can see the relationship.

Comment: No.. Amma is from Sanskrit "Amba". Grandfather is called "thatha/तात"..तात is also used for kids out of affection.. it is Sanskrit.. Parvati uses it for Ganesha in Shiva Purana. There are many such.. Pronouns are different.. Again, Dravidian classification is very recent..

Comment: This discussion is probably more suited to linguistics stack exchange. In this forum, it is not a surprise that **Sanskrit is the mother of all Indian languages** would be the mainstream opinion. @Ikshvaku There are books written on words in South Indian languages which are not and cannot be derived from Sanskrit.

Comment: @Ikshvaku many weeks later, but anyway: Malayalam and Telugu are very Sanskritic. The two languages even have prosodic sandhi and the sapta vibhaktis that Sanskrit has. Once again, this is because of Sanskrit influence. Both languages inherently came from a proto-language that was not related to Proto-Indo-European.

Comment: @AravindSuresh That's what I meant to say, that dravidian languages don't descend from sanskrit like prakrit, hindi etc do.