# Did adi shankara refuted Mimamsa's claim on Brahman's Omniscience?

Tags: philosophy, adi-shankaracharya, mimamsa

Did adi shankara debated with mimamsa scholar are refuted them on Brahman Omniscience.

Because mimamsa doesn't believe in Brahman or if they believe they do not believe Brahman alone exist or he is Omniscience.

So did adi shankara refuted mimamsa claims.

> The Purva Mimamsa school was divided on the existence of Brahman. But one thing they all agreed on was tha Brahman (if Brahman even existed) was neither the creator of the Universe, nor the author of the Vedas, **nor even omniscient**. In fact, they didn't even believe the Universe is ever created or destroyed! Here is what the Purva Mimamsa philosopher Kumarila Bhatta says in this excerpt from his Shloka Vartika:
> [(Source)](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22022/22556)