# What is Purva Mimansa Arthavada

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, terminology, purva-mimamsa, arthavada

Arthavada is a term associated with the least famous [Purva Mimansa](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6818/was-the-purva-mimansa-an-atheist-school) established by Rishi Jaimini.

What is Arthavada and how does [Uttara Mimansa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedanta) counteract against this Arthavada?