# What exactly is explanation of Hindus when they perform idol worship?

Tags: practice, idols

1. Is it they worship, the power inside idols.
2. They use it as a point of concentration.
3. Only a representation.
4. God is present in idol.

4th option included after reading question here. [What is the significance of Murthi pooja (idol worship)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/253/what-is-the-significance-of-murthi-pooja-idol-worship)

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer to this question has been given in a previous question as pointed out in comments to the question. Nevertheless, I will add an additional answer.

The clearest explanation of image worship that I have come across is that of Swami Tapasyananda:

> …Worship of a God who is not also the Absolute is idolatry, and a mere Absolute, who is characterless and is irresponsive, is not better
>   than matter. The Vedanta accepts the Supreme as both Personal and
>   Impersonal. When the votary in the course of his spiritual development
>   becomes de-personalized on achieving the elimination of his ego-based
>   body-mind, he will be able to understand the true Impersonal. Till
>   then, that is, so long as he is a person, the Impersonal and the
>   Absolute can only mean for him a Personal Being who is much more than
>   what he, a person, has grasped or can grasp of Him. To illustrate, the
>   Impersonal-Personal Divine of the Vedanta is the ocean and the God of
>   adoration of the devotee is like a big field or backwater into which
>   the water of that ocean has flowed. The many deities that form the
>   object of worship of Vedantism are like these tanks and backwaters in
>   the analogy. They are so many manifestations of the
>   Personal-Impersonal Sat-chit-ananda in the thought structures of those
>   who adore Him, or are forms adopted by Him for the achievement of
>   cosmic purposes in his world-play. The worship of these forms with an
>   understanding of the infinitude that informs their finitude ...... is
>   the only form of true worship that the human mind is capable of, so
>   long as man remains a limited person. The other ideas of the Divine
>   which Semitic religions hold – their so called boasted monotheism – is
>   only a form of disguised idolatry; for when it is said that Jehovah is
>   a jealous God, or that there is no God but Allah, it is obvious that
>   the Supreme Being is being identified as an exclusive individual and
>   not as an expression of an Infinite Being in terms of the human mind.
>   When the link with the Infinite is forgotten, a Deity, whether it is a
>   monotheistic entity or a polytheistic being becomes a mere idol. Real
>   worship of the Supreme Being is possible only when the principle of
>   Vedantic theism is understood – that principle being the perception of
>   the Infinite Personal-Impersonal Being through a limited manifestation
>   of Him.
>
> A Vedantic Deity is never aggressive, demanding the overthrow of other deities. But, a monotheistic Deity, always a jealous God, cannot
>   tolerate another deity. As Toynbee has pointed out, the monotheistic
>   Deity of the Semitics is only an apotheosis of the group or tribal
>   consciousness of certain people, a sentiment that held together
>   societies before nationalism took its place. Just as the nationalistic
>   patriotism is eager to absorb all other countries, that form of group
>   consciousness masquerading as monotheism wants to supplant all other
>   religions and establish its Deity in their sanctuaries. Proselytism,
>   for which many religions stand but which has no place in the Vedantic
>   scheme, is the consequence of the Infinite Being but a personalisation
>   of the group consciousness of a people.
>
> The principle enunciated above in regard to Deities is applicable also to worship of God in holy images, which critics, who are
>   practicing real idolatry, have stigmatised as idolatry. The Vedantin’s
>   God is not an individual as the Semite’s. He is the Universal Spirit
>   who has manifested as All-Nature. He is one with all, and if a person
>   with faith wants to see Him anywhere, He is present there. Like water
>   running all through the ground, He is everywhere; and if the well of
>   faith is dug, He becomes available for worship. A holy image is thus a
>   point at which His real presence is available for imperfect man to
>   apprehend and commune with. It is not a mere means for practising
>   concentration as some apologists say. It is much more. It is a point
>   of real communion with the Divine when the eye of faith reveals Him as
>   accepting the worship and offering made by the devotee.

[Adapted from Swami Tapasyananda’s introductory remarks in ‘A Primer of Hinduism’ by D.S.Sarma]

Comment: It is a point of real communion with the Divine.. please cite scriptural reference for the claim of XYZ

Comment: Read Sri Ramakrishna's life by Swami Saradananda where he directly experience the divine present in Dakshineswar Kali temple. The idea has arisen from the experience of Yogis.